# Filtrar diferentes columnas de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html5, tablas, filtro

Necesito ayuda con esta tabla que estoy haciendo con filtros.
Les dejo mi código por acá:
HTML

```
<table class="tabla">
<tr>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Descripción</th>
   <th>Medidas (mm)</th>
   <th>Capacidad de carga (kg./m2)</th>
   <th>Color <select id='filterText' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText()'>
                            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
                            <option value='Blanco'>Blanco</option>
                            <option value='Negro'>Negro</option>
                            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
</select></th>
<th>Material</th>
</tr>

<tr class="content">
<td>SP0553</td>

<td>Piso plástico relleno</td>      

<td>325x325x30</td>

<td>500</td>

<td>Blanco</td>

<td>Virgen</td>
</tr>

<tr class="content">
<td>SP0554</td>

<td>Piso plástico relleno</td>      

<td>325x325x30</td>

<td>500</td>

<td>Negro</td>

<td>Reciclado</td>
</tr>

  <tr class="content">
 <td>SP0559</td>

 <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>     

 <td>500x500x50</td>

 <td>1000</td>

 <td>Blanco</td>

 <td>Virgen</td>
 </tr>


 <tr class="content">
 <td>SP0560</td>

 <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>     

 <td>500x500x50</td>

 <td>1000</td>

 <td>Negro</td>

 <td>Reciclado</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function filterText()
{  
    var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val());
    if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.content').filter(function() {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
    }
    }

 function clearFilter()
   {
    $('.filterText').val('');
    $('.content').show();
   }
 </script>
```

Como verán, hay solo un filtro funcionando en la parte de "Color". Pero yo necesito poner un filtro parecido en cada `th`, o sea, un filtro para cada columna, y que se apliquen todos y pueda tener múltiples filtros. La idea es que el usuario pueda filtrar la categoría (una o más) que quiera.
Intenté copiando el código en otro `th`, pero solo funciona el primer filtro.

Si a alguien se le ocurre una manera diferente para hacer esto, o una manera de mejorar mi código, bienvenido sea! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razon por la que solo te funciona el primer `th` es porque estas usando `id`, y el id debe de ser unico.  En lugar de `id` utiliza clases.  Te dejo un ejemplo con 2 selects funcionando:

```js
function filterText(select)
{  
    var rex = new RegExp($(select).val());
    if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
        
        $('.content:visible').filter(function() {
        return !rex.test($(this).text());
        }).hide();
    }
    }

 function clearFilter()
   {
    $('.filterText').val('');
    $('.content').show();
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tabla">
<tr>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Descripción</th>
   <th>Medidas (mm)<select class='filterText' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
                            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
                            <option value='325x'>325x325x30</option>
                            <option value='500x'>500x500x50</option>
                            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
</select></th>
   <th>Capacidad de carga (kg./m2)</th>
   <th>Color <select class='filterText' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
                            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
                            <option value='Blanco'>Blanco</option>
                            <option value='Negro'>Negro</option>
                            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
</select></th>
<th>Material</th>
</tr>

<tr class="content">
<td>SP0553</td>

<td>Piso plástico relleno</td>      

<td>325x325x30</td>

<td>500</td>

<td>Blanco</td>

<td>Virgen</td>
</tr>

<tr class="content">
<td>SP0554</td>

<td>Piso plástico relleno</td>      

<td>325x325x30</td>

<td>500</td>

<td>Negro</td>

<td>Reciclado</td>
</tr>

  <tr class="content">
 <td>SP0559</td>

 <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>     

 <td>500x500x50</td>

 <td>1000</td>

 <td>Blanco</td>

 <td>Virgen</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="content">
 <td>SP0560</td>

 <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>     

 <td>500x500x50</td>

 <td>1000</td>

 <td>Negro</td>

 <td>Reciclado</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Genial, eso es lo que buscaba! Y puedo poner un filtro en cada columna de esa manera, no es cierto?

Comment: Correcto @CarlaPaludetto.

Comment: Genial, gracias! Ahí estuve probando, y veo que funciona correctamente hasta cierto punto. En algunos casos, cuando borro un filtro y busco otra opción, no me muestra nada, o incluso a veces no filtra. Esto por qué puede suceder?

Comment: Este codigo filtra unicamente las filas visibles.

Comment: Claro, pero los valores que puse en el filtro están puestos para que siempre traiga por lo menos un resultado! Y a veces no realiza ninguna acción. Copié y pegué el código del `select` en la parte de Capacidad de Carga, y no logro hacer que me muestre las filas con el filtro 500

Comment: Yo tambien probe primero con esa columna, el problema es que el valor 500 esta presente en todas las filas.  Si quieres aplicar ese filtro tendrias que agregar mas logica.

Comment: Entiendo. Lamentablemente voy a tener que dejarlo así, porque son las medidas que me pidieron. Igualmente tu respuesta es la solución perfecta que estaba buscando. Ahora la aplicaré al resto de las tablas. Muchísimas gracias! (:

Comment: De nada @CarlaPaludetto.

Comment: Te hago una última consulta. Me pasa que cuando cambio el valor en algún filtro (por ejemplo, pongo primero el filtro del color "blanco" y después "negro") se traba y no me trae resultados. Eso se puede solucionar de alguna manera? Porque hay filas con el resultado "negro" y no se muestran

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88261/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-carla-paludetto).